# On the list of Pages, clicking to Edit a particular page redirects to the list of trash

Tags: pages, homepage

Here's the background. I created a page called "New Home Page" to eventually replace the original "Home" page. When I was ready, I renamed the original Home page to "Old Home" and reset the Settings > Reading  to the "New Home Page."

Now, when I click to edit the page, it redirects to a listing of the pages in the Trash. I permanently deleted the old home page, but still the same results. So, I can't edit the new home page.

All other pages are fine.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I traced the problem to what must have been a fluke in the autosaves for that page. Once I deleted the autosaves, I was able to edit the page. In reviewing the core code, I didn't see anything that would cause the function to redirect to the listing of pages in the trash. FWIW, the `post_name` name column looked like this before the delete:

```
6609-revision-v1               
6609-revision-v1               
6609-revision-v1              
6609-revision-v1               
6609-autosave-v1               
6609-autosave-v1             
6609-revision-v1
```